# ASP.NET 4.0 Mail using Gmail (Google Apps)

Tags: asp.net, gmail

We have set up a web site for a client who uses Google Apps for their emails.

In the web site's contact us section, we have a form to enable a visitor send them a message. In short, the below code is used but it always times out during the 'send' phaze.

```
Dim mysmtp = New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
mysmtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
mysmtp.Port = 465
mysmtp.EnableSsl = True
mysmtp.Timeout = 15000 ' it times out a lot later after removing this..


Dim msg As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
msg = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from:="info@xxx.org", subject:="text", body:="still testing ...", [to]:="xx@gmail.com")


Dim smtpAuthentication As New System.Net.NetworkCredential()

smtpAuthentication.Password = "mypwd"
smtpAuthentication.UserName = "info@xxx.org"
mysmtp.Credentials = smtpAuthentication
mysmtp.Send(msg)
```

I have tried it with firewall turned off, and anti-virus software disabled. I am using windows 7.

None of the solutions in other questions/forms worked. The problem might not be the code but I am lost.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you're not perhaps sitting behind a network firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with port 587. Here is how the SMTP should be configured.

```
Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtp.Port = 587
smtp.EnableSsl = True
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
smtp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("info@xxx.org", "mypwd")
```

And if it still doesn't work, fire up Command Prompt and do this.

1. Open the Start menu, and select Run.
2. Enter command in the Open: field, and click OK.
3. Enter 'telnet smtp.gmail.com 465,' and hit Enter, or if you're using Outlook 2007, enter 'telnet smtp.gmail.com 587' instead. (Does the information in the prompt window clear? If not, please note the message that appears.)
4. Close the prompt window.

Google help center link: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78775

Comment: thank you! Port was the problem as well as the UseDefaultCredentials. Can you explain what are the default credentials for people running into the same problem?

Comment: no. i usually setdefaultcredentials = false as per a suggestion from stackoverflow at another post